# summernote styleTags along with toolbar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, summernote

Summernote give options to custom toolbar like

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']]
  ]
});
```

& than for setting h1, h2 etc

```
$(".summernote").summernote({
    styleTags: ['h1', 'h2']
});
```

But how to use the both in single method like ?

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  styleTags: ['h1', 'h2'],
  toolbar: [
    // [groupName, [list of button]]
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']]
  ]
});
```

I have tried multipe variations but not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add 'style' button to your btns group.

Try code below.

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
    toolbar: [
         ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']],
         ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph', 'style']],
    ],
    styleTags: ['p', 'h4'],
});
```

Comment: whats the difference in what you suggested and  used in question after "But how to use the both in single method like"

Comment: The difference is that my toolbar[1] have 'style' in array.
It`s like some kind of placeholder for styleTags dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

```
    toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph', 'style']],
                ['height', ['height']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'hr']],
                ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
                ['help', ['help']]
            ],
            styleTags: ['p','pre', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6'],
```